# Could someone synonymize [neologism] and [coin]?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tag-synonyms

21 [neologism] vs. 2 [coin].  I don't have the required upvotes in the tag to suggest the synonym.  Could a mod do this?

Comment: @wai see my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Obligatory answer stating completion so this does not show up as an unanswered question.

Comment: I don't understand this? Why must this question have an off-topic answer?